Get VSCode to recognize aliases
Ok, so I built an app with Vite and React. I added some aliases to make things easier to read, it works, but VSC is dumb and doesn't pick up on the aliases, which also means it has trouble inferring types and so on.
It's especially dumb since, for instance, @store gets highlighted as being a problem, but @store/index works perfectly. What am I doing wrong here?!
/* vite.config.ts */

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import path from "path";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
      "@assets": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/assets"),
      "@core": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/core"),
      "@store": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/core/store"),
      "@user": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/user"),
    },
  },
});

/* tsconfig.app.json */ 

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,

    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["*"],
      "@assets/*": ["assets/*"],
      "@core/*": ["core/*"],
      "@store/*": ["core/store/*"],
      "@user/*": ["user/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}

Again, it works, it does compile and run, and I didn't even have to add the aliases to the tsconfig file - which makes sense, I hate having to add it to 2 separate places anyway. But VSCode is still being dumb...


Please share the folder structure for more accurate answers, you can use the tree -I node_modules command

you can see the folder structure in the paths themselves. as I said, the code does work, it's just that VSC does not recognize the aliases

Can you change the tsconfig file name from tsconfig.app.js to tsconfig.json in addition to the changed I suggested in my answer?

wouldn't that break Vite? it's not me who created that file, Vite aparently makes them, a tsconfig.app.json and a tsconfig.node.json then references them both in the actual tsconfig.json file

Change the path aliases to use a recursive wildcard ./**/* in your tsconfig.json.
  "paths": {
    "@/*": ["./**/*"],
    "@assets/*": ["./assets/**/*"],
    "@core/*": ["./core/**/*"],
    "@store/*": ["./core/store/**/*"],
    "@user/*": ["./user/**/*"]
  }


and no, that doesn't work...
